# Is there surface tension between a solid and a liquid?

Tags: forces, material-science, surface-tension

The molecules of a solid are so tightly bound together that they are fixed in position unlike in a liquid or gas where they may move freely. In that case it seems like the surface tension between the liquid and solid would be zero as the solid is so rigid there are no forces acting within it that will lead to the shape of its surface deforming.

So the surface tension in this case is zero? Is that correct?

Comment: Are you asking if a solid has surface tension? and then asking if you put it at the interface with a liquid, then that surface tension of the solid is zero?

Comment: Well I was under the impression that surface tension is due to a material and its interface with another medium. In this case surface tension due to solid and its interface with a liquid.

Comment: If you drop a small marble into a cup of water will there be surface tension at the surface of the marble?

Comment: This may help: http://www.answers.com/Q/Does_a_solid_have_surface_tension.

Comment: Not so sure I agree with that answers.com post. Atoms at a surf. have less bonds and will relax differently than atoms within the bulk leading to different elastic prop. This leads to a surf. free energy dens. $f_s = C^s_{ijkl} \epsilon^s_{ij} \epsilon_{kl}^s$ where $s$ denotes the projection of the tensor onto the surf. plane regardless of the medium the solid is in. Also $C^s_{ijkl}$ is related to an instrinsic surf. stress.

In fact, some works show from the framework of DFT that there is a surf. tension that arises in some materials. See

JAP 111, 124305 (2012) and PRL 109, 156104 (2012)

Comment: Also see

Archive for Rational Mechanics and Analysis
21. VII. 1975, Volume 57, Issue 4, pp 291-323
by M. E. Gurtin, A. I. Murdoch 

which discussing a nonvanishing residual stress at the surface.

Incidentally, and not to go on a tangent, but in the interest of plugging some of my own work and others, the presence of the surface strains can lead to misfit strains that can modulate elastic dependent properties in nanoscale systems, see

Nano Lett., 2015, 15 (6) (2015), pp 4089–4095 and Phys. Rev. Applied 4, 014001 (2015)--

Note that including a liquid is a completely different situation here

Comment: @JohnM This link seems to contradict the link you posted above - https://www.reddit.com/r/askscience/comments/15a1iw/do_solid_objects_have_a_surface_tension/ - so with some resources saying solids do have surface tension..and some saying they don't, which am I supposed to trust?

Comment: The reddit thread seems to point to the fact that solids do have a surface tension, which is what I am saying; see molecularminding's comments..

Comment: Sorry I meant to direct that at Ernie!

Answer (score 3):

Surface tension is equivalent to an interfacial energy. They are equivalent because if you increase the area of the interface you increase the energy of the interface, so you have to do work. The work done is the surface tension of the interface times the increase in area.

So we can associate a surface tension to gas-solid or liquid-solid interfaces even though the solid can't flow. These surface tensions are not some hypothetical quantity but have real physical significance, for example [in the calculation of contact angles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contact_angle#Thermodynamics).

Comment: In a liquid-liquid or liquid-gas flow, at the interphase between the phases, the normal forces from each phase are balanced with the force surface tension. $\sum_{k = 1,2} M_k = M_m$ where $M_k$ are the normal forces and $M_m$ is a force due to the surface tension. But in a liquid-solid flow is it the case that $M_m = 0$ and hence the normal forces from each phase are balanced, ie. $M_1 = M_2$?

Comment: No that isn't the case in general. See this paper:
 https://www.utd.edu/~son051000/my_publications/contactangle_jmathchem2009.pdf

Comment: Looks like it's time for an "assumption" so! :D

Answer (score -1):

Work done by surface tension always comes from reducing the surface area.     There is no surface tension on a dry solid because a solid does not deform spontaneously and thus cannot reduce its surface area.

However, the question here was on surface tension between a solid and a liquid. This situation can be viewed from the liquid's side as well! Hence, the answer is: yes.

Comment: One can view surface reconstructions as a deformation of the surface, and they are driven by free energy considerations (and happen spontaneously). So, your first paragraph is incorrect.

Comment: The argument was on reducing the surface area. Surface reconstruction does not specifically reduce the total surface area, and even if it did, this would happen within milliseconds after creating the surface. Note also that surface tension is defined in a way that is unrelated to reconstruction.